# How to Create PDF file using Excel sheet using R?

Tags: r, pdf

I am searching for a way to create PDF files automatically using R. I saw people suggesting the RDCOMClient option, but it doesn't work for my PC.

How to create pdf file using excel sheet in R?

Input file: file.xlsx

Output file: file.pdf

Input:
[image: excel sheet image]

Expected Output:
[image: pdf image]

I thought to create a pdf file with the pdf() function for Data frame but I only managed to save the tables through the grid.table() function, but it is not creating exact pdf file.

```
pdf("file.pdf")
grid.table(df)
dev.off()
```

Does anyone have better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two functions that you can consider :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

save_Excel_As_PDF <- function(path_To_Excel_File,
                              path_To_PDF_File)
{
  xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
  xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File)
  xlWbk$ExportAsFixedFormat(Type = 0, FileName = path_To_PDF_File)
  xlWbk$Close()
  xlApp$Quit()
}

save_Excel_Sheet_As_PDF <- function(path_To_Excel_File,
                                    path_To_PDF_File,
                                    sheet_Id)
{
  xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
  xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File)
  sheet <- xlWbk $Worksheets()$Item(sheet_Id)
  sheet$Select()

  # Type = 0 => PDF, Type = 1 => XPS
  xlWbk[["ActiveSheet"]]$ExportAsFixedFormat(Type = 0, Filename = path_To_PDF_File,
                                             IgnorePrintAreas = FALSE)

  xlWbk$Close()
  xlApp$Quit()
}
```

I use these functions at my job and they work very well.